# Concatenate each word in a vector to form a single string in r

Tags: r, stringr

I am trying to combine the values of a vector to a single string separated with `|` in between each concatenation.

For example:

```
library(tidyverse)

sample_df <- data.frame("sample_col" = c("Audi","BMW","MG","Hyundai","Kia"),
                        "value" = c(22,44,66,88,19))
```

Tried:

```
paste(sample_df$sample_col, "|")
```

output

```
[1] "Audi |"     "BMW |"       "MG |"        "Hyundai |"   "Kia|"
```

Need Result like:

```
Audi |BMW |MG |Hyundai |Kia|
```

I am trying to do this as I will be searching each word mentioned above and `str_detect(col_name, pattern = sample_df$sample_col)` doesn't work correctly and to be able to search each word I need them in

```
str_detect(col_name,pattern = "word1|word2|word3")
```

format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```r
library(tidyverse)

str_c(sample_df$sample_col, collapse = "|")

#> [1] "Audi|BMW|MG|Hyundai|Kia"
```